# Friendly URL for pure HTML web site

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have this pure HTML web site published on GoDaddy. What I want to do is create some friendly URL, such as: www.mywebsite.com/friendly-url

The easiest way of doing it is to create a folder called "friendly-url" and put a index.html file on this folder, right?

Is there any easier/correct way of doing it?

And the second question would be: can I create like an alias for a specific page? Let's say I want these both URLs to point to the same page:

- www.mywebsite.com/friendly-url
- www.mywebsite.com/furl

Please keep in mind this is a simple and pure HTML web site hosted on GoDaddy and I only have access to cPanel.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mod_Rewrite by putting a .htaccess file in your web root directory. this could help you a little more on how to do it: http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php
--Edit
You can also have a visit at this website: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708